# Can Video For Windows (VFW) allow multiple video streams in one file?

Tags: winapi, video, video-capture, video-processing

There is not much theory or documentation on the concepts of streams and samples in Video For Windows API (VFW). I am wondering if a video should only contain:

- one video stream
- one audio stream

Or can a video contain multiple video streams (one after the other) and multiple audio streams?

I assume a "sample" just means one frame of the video, not multiple frames.
I assume a stream, is a collection of frames or collection of samples. So it would be useful to divide a video into multiple streams (collections of frames) to make multiple "sections", or multiple streams

If you cannot have multiple streams in a video, and this api is only designed to have one video stream per video (with an optional audio stream), how would one create a video composed of multiple sections? Just edit/cut/paste directly into a single stream? Or use a different API such as MediaFoundation/DirectShow instead?

Comment: Sections are what exactly? How would they appear in a video player? But VFW is ancient. Don't use it.

Comment: Well after researching it a bit: I think one can create sections by combining multiple streams and then saving it as a single file as a single stream... with AVISave() function. I agree VFW is very ancient but some old code relies on it... so it's still useful, but risky using it as it could be no longer supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's doable via plain VfW but apparently the AVI format *does* support multiple video streams. I found [a thread](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/319455-How-to-Demux-avi-with-multiple-video-streams) which has samples from a Fujifilm Finepix Real3D W1 camera with dual video streams:

```
  Duration: 00:00:02.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9676 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 320x240, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      strn            : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0200
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 11024 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 320x240, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      strn            : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0200
```

Posters offered advice on how to split such a video. Among the options were `ffmpeg` and DirectShow-based software (GrpahEdit and GraphStudioNext); I suspect you can use them to create such a video as well.

Comment: do the video streams play one after the other as a single video, or is it something like audio streams where the user can select which audio stream to play (english track, french track, commentary track, etc.)..
In order for streams to play after each other, they would have to be ordered, and the player would need to know in what order to play them

Comment: no, they play simultaneously. If you want to just concatenate two videos to play one after another, you don't need parallel streams. For details, check how VirtualDub  does it.

Comment: Interesting, they play on top of each other mixed laced together? my brain cannot figure out how that would work, though.. if you had transparency, and played them on top of each other, that would make for some interesting effects and use cases.

Comment: Well, how it's actually handled is player-specific.I could get the sample to play with VLC and it showed two windows playing at the same time. I imagine a stereo-aware player could play them on the different sides of the screen or something... Or maybe some players could allow switching between streams, like angles on DVDs.